# Animated gif File In NSImageView eats the Memory (Mac Development)

Tags: macos, memory-leaks, animated-gif, nsimageview

I just try to put Animated gif file with 6 frames acquired from url Request and create nsimage with the response ,,, then set the Image in NSImageView ...

I use this

```
// Where returnedImage is nsImage I created with response of the connection ..
    [myImageView setImage:[response returnedImage]];
```

I use this code to change the Image displayed when some user actions happen

I observe that The memory allocated to the program is increased linearly with large scale .. and the application might crash

I make sure that my code has no leaks ...

I do not Know why it is increases , do I have to release the previous Image that was set

Any Idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I delete and recreate the NSImageView In the Nib File ... I may be an xcode Deployment bug or something ,,, But i was allocate some memory to graphics card continuously increasing